# How to set Qt QStateMachine animation duration

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to learn the Qt framework. My QStateMachine code does the correct thing (pressing the button makes the chat window popup change size).
I can't change the speed of the animation to get a nice visual transition.
Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
   widget.setupUi( this );

   // chat window - Chat button opens
   ChatWindowClosedState = new QState();
   ChatWindowOpenState = new QState();

   ChatWindowOpenGeometry = widget.groupBox->geometry();
   ChatWindowClosedGeometry = widget.pushButton->geometry();
   ChatWindowClosedGeometry.translate( -ChatWindowClosedGeometry.width(), 0 );

   ChatWindowClosedState->assignProperty( widget.groupBox, "geometry", ChatWindowClosedGeometry );
   ChatWindowOpenState->assignProperty( widget.groupBox, "geometry", ChatWindowOpenGeometry );

   ChatWindowCloseTransition = ChatWindowClosedState->addTransition( widget.pushButton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), ChatWindowOpenState );
   ChatWindowCloseAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation( widget.pushButton, "geometry" );
   ChatWindowCloseAnimation->setDuration( 5000 );
   ChatWindowCloseTransition->addAnimation( ChatWindowCloseAnimation );

   ChatWindowOpenTransition = ChatWindowOpenState->addTransition( widget.pushButton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), ChatWindowClosedState );
   ChatWindowOpenAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation( widget.pushButton, "geometry" );
   ChatWindowOpenAnimation->setDuration( 5000 );
   ChatWindowOpenTransition->addAnimation( ChatWindowOpenAnimation );

   machine = new QStateMachine( this );
   machine->addState( ChatWindowClosedState );
   machine->addState( ChatWindowOpenState );
   machine->setInitialState( ChatWindowClosedState );
   machine->start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code

```
ChatWindowOpenAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation( widget.pushButton, "geometry" );
```

should be

```
ChatWindowOpenAnimation = new QPropertyAnimation( widget.groupBox, "geometry" );
```

The animation was being applied to the wrong widget.